# Is "post-apocalyptically" a valid word?

Tags: single-word-requests, is-it-a-word

- I found *apocalyptically*, but not with *post-*.
- I'm trying to say **in a way that is post-apocalyptic**.

Example:
Post-apocalyptically-scented outdoors.

Comment: I'm perfectly familiar with *post-apocalyptic* - it gives me a pretty good idea what to expect if I'm told some movie is set in a *post-apocalyptic world*, for example. But what on earth would *post-apocalyptic scent* be? I know the [Mad Max](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Max) movies always seem to major on burning rubber and gasoline, but surely that's not the definitive smell for all post-apocalyptic contexts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you think it expresses your meaning and that your readers will understand and respond positively to it, then there's no reason why you shouldn't use it. That's a more relevant consideration than whether or not it's a 'valid word', whatever that may mean.

Comment: Wise words indeed.

Comment: Yes; otherwise, we would be waiting an unconscionably long time to see it become a valid word.

Comment: I commented to the question above, before reading your answer. All I can say is that *if OP thinks it expresses his meaning* is only half the story. It's also necessary (or at least highly desirable) that *his audience/readership should understand that meaning*. I certainly don't have any trustworthy concept of what *post-apocalytic* means in relation to OP's example "scent".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Hence my carefully chosen words 'If you think . . . that your readers will understand and respond positively to it'.

Comment: I think we can safely say *your* words express your meaning, and *your* readers should understand them. I was just emphasising the second condition of your "if" because most likely OP wouldn't be asking if he didn't think *his* words met the first condition. But in his case the second would be far less likely to obtain.

Answer (score 4):

As long as the word follows standard rules, and as long as it communicates your meaning, there is no reason why it wouldn't be valid.  Remember that the dictionary doesn't define the language; it's the other way round.  Also, most dictionaries will not contain every single conglomeration of prefixes (such as *post-*) added onto every noun, adjective, and adverb (such as *apocalyptically*)  Your reasoning could run thus: *apocalyptic* is a adjective, and *-ly* appended to an adjective means the adverb form, so *apocalyptically* is a word. *Post-* is a prefix, and can be added to any word with which it makes sense, so *post-apocalyptically* is completely valid, even if it's not common.

That said, *post-apocalyptically* has a respectable number of [google hits](https://www.google.com/search?ix=heb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22post-apocalyptically%22) (699), and Dictionary.com has both *apocalyptically* and *postapocalyptic* as variations on [*apocalyptic*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apocalyptic).

Answer (score 3):

It may not be in any published dictionary, but:

- it is a standard and grammatical use of suffixes and prefixes.
- it doesn't strain the bounds of cognition.
- it doesn't sound weird

The first is enough, but the other two might detract.

So the short answer is, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both usages work well to describe an end of the world type of smell. In a post-apocalyptic world, we can expect to smell smoke, rust, and rotten odors.

Therefore, the smell really depends on how the world ended: nuclear war, disease, invasion, zombie outbreak, etc. We can smell the world post-apocalyptically and apocalyptically. *Apocalyptically* is more an adjective to describe the type of smell.